# problems with java toLowerCase function when using arrays and multiple 'words' in the string

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, split, java.util.scanner

I am exceptionally new to java, as in, I can barely write 20 lines of basic code and have them work, level of new, I have 2 issues which may or may not be related as they are from very similar pieces of code that I have personally written.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringCW {


public static void main (String [] args) {

    String word = ""; 

    while(!(word.equals("stop"))){


        Scanner capconversion = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter word:" );

        word = capconversion.next(); 
        String lower = word.toLowerCase();
        word = lower;
        System.out.println("conversion = " + word);

    }


    System.out.println("ending program");


        }
    }
}
```

This is my first chunk of code, it is designed to take any string and convert it into lowercase, however if I am to print anything seperated by a space, eg: "WEWEFRDWSRGdfgdfg DFGDFGDFG" only the first 'word' will be printed and converted, I am also getting a memory leak from cap conversion, though I don't understand what that means or how to fix it

My second problem is likely along the same lines

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class splitstring {

private static Scanner capconversion;

public static void main (String [] args) {

    String word = ""; 

    while(!(word.equals("stop"))){

        capconversion = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter word:" );

        word = capconversion.next(); 
        String lower = word.toLowerCase();
        String[] parts = lower.split(" ");
        parts [0] = "";
        parts [1] = "";
        parts [2] = "";
        parts [3] = "";
        parts [4] = "";


        System.out.println("conversion = " + lower
        parts [0] + parts [1] + parts [2] + parts [3] + parts [4]);

        }

        System.out.println("ending program");
    }
}
```

this is the 2nd chunk of code and is designed to do the same job as the previous one except print out each 'word' on a new line, then return to the input part until the stop command is entered

the error I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at splitstring.main(splitstring.java:21)
```

however I don't understand where the error is coming in

Comment: What is `splitstring.java:21`? Please adhere to Java naming conventions, classes should be in `PascalCase`.

Comment: I copy pasted the error message I got, I'm using eclipse as my coding program, and as I said, I don't know much about java so I was hoping to get help from you guys

Comment: It tells you that the error is on line 21. What is line 21?

Comment: line 21 is      parts [1] = "";

Comment: Don't create the `Scanner` every time around the loop.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the memory leak.  Each time you input a string, it creates a new `String`, which uses up memory.  The older strings that are no longer used will eventually have their memory reclaimed, but the Java Virtual Machine will do that when it gets around to it, unless your program exits first.  In general, you need to be writing a much larger and more complex program before you have to worry about memory leaks.  But creating a `Scanner` only once is a very good idea.

Comment: @ajb the memory leak is that the scanner isn't closed...

Comment: @BoristheSpider OK, then.  I didn't spot that until David's comment.

Comment: Thanks for that, I took the scanner outside of the while loop and it fixed the leak, I'm doing a degree so I would appreciate an explanation on how to 'patch' a leak like that if I didn't know what was causing it, or even what causes a memory leak in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using `Scanner.next()`, which returns a single token - and which uses whitespace as a token separator by default.

Perhaps you should use `nextLine()` instead, if you want to capture a whole line at a time?

As for your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` - that has basically the same cause. You're calling `split` on a single word, so the array returned has only one element (element 0). When you try to set element 1, that's outside the bounds of the array, hence the exception.

Note that nothing in here really has anything to do with `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: That's great, it fixed the issue in the first segment of code, however I still get the error message in the 2nd, after swapping out: next() for nextLine()

Comment: @BenBowen: Well did you look at my explanation for that? You're assuming that `split` is returning an array with at least 5 elements. Why are you hard-coding the access to `parts[0]`, `parts[1]` etc at all? Hint: use `parts.length` to find out how many elements the array has...

Comment: I've made a few attempts at using your suggestions and I couldnt really find a way to do it .I did read your first explanation however it didn't make sense to me until I read the 2nd part you posted. Thanks for the parts.length suggestion, it makes more sense however how would I get an integer value from the user input to set a length to the array?

Comment: @BenBowen: You're creating the array with `split` - the user input is already determining the length of the array.